# amazon sp api UpdateVerificationStatus

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am working on amazon sp API and I want to update the order verification status. I am using jlevers/selling-partner-api

From where and how can I get this value.

external_reviewer_id

for UpdateVerificationStatusRequestBody

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcSBs.png)

Comment: Did you find anything, i am also working on it but there is no externalReviewerId.

Comment: Not yet. You can check this issue answered by the writer of SDK.

https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api/issues/331